# give permission to Django to use specific software in shell

Tags: 18.04, permissions, python, exiftool

I need to call `exiftool` in shell by django but it's seem django can't use this software.when i run `exiftool -j <image>` myself in terminal that is working well but in django the result in `None` that i think shown django can't use it. the below code shown how i use `exiftool` in django:

```
 cmd_get_meta = 'exiftool -j "{filename}"'.format(filename=filename)
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd_get_meta,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                               shell=True)
    raw_result = process.communicate()
    meta = json.loads(str(raw_result[0], 'utf-8'))[0]
```

`raw-result` is None after i call process and its shown me below error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

i must notice that i run django with uwsgi but i don't know by which user running.sorry but i'm new in Ubuntu and my knowledge about users and permission is not enough.if you need any more information please let me know.thank you

---

i run `ps aux | grep exiftool` and `ps aux | grep uwsgi` and the result is :

```
$ ps aux | grep uwsgi   
backend   1243  0.0  0.0  14224   988 pts/9    S+   14:52   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn uwsgi
www-data 20469  0.0  0.7 222664 63984 ?        S     2018  32:55 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/hamclassy.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/hamclassy.log
www-data 32357  0.0  0.8 473188 67804 ?        Sl   14:18   0:00 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/hamclassy.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/hamclassy.log
www-data 32358  0.0  0.8 473188 67436 ?        Sl   14:18   0:00 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/hamclassy.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/hamclassy.log
www-data 32362  0.0  0.8 476604 67700 ?        Sl   14:18   0:00 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/hamclassy.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/hamclassy.log
www-data 32363  0.0  0.8 472792 67296 ?        Sl   14:18   0:00 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/hamclassy.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/hamclassy.log
www-data 32368  0.0  0.9 482496 74316 ?        Sl   14:18   0:01 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/hamclassy.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/hamclassy.log
www-data 32372  0.0  0.8 476348 67296 ?        Sl   14:18   0:00 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/hamclassy.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/hamclassy.log
www-data 32376  0.0  0.8 477884 69996 ?        Sl   14:18   0:01 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/hamclassy.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/hamclassy.log
www-data 32377  0.0  0.8 477116 68968 ?        Sl   14:18   0:00 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/hamclassy.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/hamclassy.log
```

```
$ ps aux | grep exiftool
backend   1233  0.0  0.0  14224  1016 pts/9    S+   14:52   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn exiftool
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that exiftool is in a PATH that django can access?  Strip it down to a basic command that tries to run exiftool and prints the result (no JSON decoding).  Test using the full path to exiftool.

Comment: yes it's working. I run some command in several directory without use sudo and it's working